# OAuth2 Authentication fails when attempting to change Gmail Signature for domain user

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm trying to implement a script that will iterate through each user on my domain and set a custom signature to match company requirements. According to the forum post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257996/new-gmail-api-signatures-settings) I can do this if I create an Apps Script run as a service account with domain-wide delegation. I've created my service account, and made sure the delegation is set to domain-wide. I also added the OAuth2 library to my project. Running this code with my own email address, I get the error message 'Access not granted or expired. (line 352, file "Service", project "OAuth2").' I tried reaching out to Google cloud support for help implementing OAuth2, and they sent me here. Could I get assistance getting this to work on my domain and move in the right direction?

My current code version:

```js
var EMAIL = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

var SERVICEACCT = {
  clientID: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('clientId'),
  fileText: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('clientSecretFile'), 
  projectID: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('clientProjectID'),
  privateKeyID: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('privateKeyID'),
  privateKey: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('clientSecretKey'),
  clientEmail: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('clientEmail'),
  authURL: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('clientAuthURI'),
  tokenURL: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('clientTokenURI'),
  providerURL: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('providerCertURL'),
  clientURL: PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('clientCertURL'),
  map : PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys()
};


function gmailSignatureImage() {
   Logger.log(SERVICEACCT.clientEmail);
    var email = EMAIL;

  var service = getDomWideDelegationService('Gmail: ', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing', email);

    var resource = { signature: '<div><strong>My signature image</strong></div>' +
          '<div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/251px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" '+ 
          'alt="" border="0" /></div>' };

    var requestBody                = {};
    requestBody.headers            = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()};
    requestBody.method             = "PUT";
    requestBody.contentType        = "application/json";
    requestBody.payload            = JSON.stringify(resource);
    requestBody.muteHttpExceptions = false;

    var emailForUrl = encodeURIComponent(email);
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/sendAs/' + emailForUrl;
    var setSignatureResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestBody);
}


// these two things are included in the .JSON file that you download when creating the service account and service account key
    var OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY  = SERVICEACCT.privateKey;
    var OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL = SERVICEACCT.clientEmail;


function getDomWideDelegationService(serviceName, scope, email) {

    Logger.log('starting getDomainWideDelegationService for email: ' + email);

    return OAuth2.createService(serviceName + email)
    // Set the endpoint URL.
    //.setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
      .setTokenUrl(SERVICEACCT.tokenURL)
    // Set the private key and issuer.
    .setPrivateKey(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
    .setIssuer(OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL)

    // Set the name of the user to impersonate. This will only work for
    // Google Apps for Work/EDU accounts whose admin has setup domain-wide
    // delegation:
    // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
    .setSubject(email)

    // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

    // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
    // setup of domain-wide delegation.
    .setScope(scope);

 }
```

Also, here are the results of printing my SERVICEACCT object to console (sanitized for privacy):

```js
[17-03-28 13:32:13:515 EDT] Service Account
[17-03-28 13:32:13:515 EDT] Client ID: 1234567891011121314
[17-03-28 13:32:13:516 EDT] Project ID: project-id-12345678910112
[17-03-28 13:32:13:516 EDT] Private Key ID: 871**CONFIDENTIAL DATA**ad60
[17-03-28 13:32:13:517 EDT] Client Email: gsig-828@project-id-[Project ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com
[17-03-28 13:32:13:518 EDT] Auth URI: : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
[17-03-28 13:32:13:518 EDT] Token URI: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
[17-03-28 13:32:13:519 EDT] Provider Certification URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs
[17-03-28 13:32:13:519 EDT] Client Certification URL: https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/[projectID].iam.gserviceaccount.com
[17-03-28 13:32:13:519 EDT] Private Key: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----***CONFIDENTIAL KEY***\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Service is authorized. You may refer with this [related thread](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/issues/20) which suggested to reset the service / clear your use properties. *Google only returns the refresh token the first time you authorize the service, so if it was lost then it won't be restored in future authorizations.* Also, try revoking access for this script / project and reauthorizing.

> I have revoked all access and then I generated the license again far it works, I'll wait a while and see if it does not expire again.
>
> Once you give permission not remove access to the application. I guess with this permission Google refresh the token.

Here's another SO post which might help: [Automated OAuth2 token not working - Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781884/automated-oauth2-token-not-working-google-apps-script)

Comment: Since I am very new to Google OAuth2 authentication, I'm going to have to take this one step at a time.... When you say 'revoke access,' do you mean to delete the service account and create a new one? I'm looking at the properties of the service account I made and I can disable G-Suite domain authentication, create a key, or delete the account. Should I create a new key?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added **Service Account** to Domain Wide Delegation on Google Admin?

If not then you have to do it for the Script to have access.
https://admin.google.com/

Or try this link https://admin.google.com/ac/owl/domainwidedelegation directly.
You need to add there all privilages that your client will need to set up those actions.

> I had the same issue and it solved it for me.

Apart from that I think your code looks ok.